# Strawberry Perl -- where are encoding conversions done by default?

Tags: windows, powershell, perl, unicode

Basically, I wrote a Perl script that creates an encoded command for Powershell and tries to run it. I had to explicitly convert the command string to utf-16 before base64-encoding it. I'm wondering why that's **all** I had to do get the script to work. What conversions is Perl on Windows*  performing by default in the run of an "ordinary" program that interacts with the console and perhaps the file system? For instance, is argv converted? Is stdin/stdout converted? Does file IO go through a conversion?

✱ in particular, the Strawberry Perl distribution in case ActivePerl does something different

---

I'm trying to write a Perl script that calls many PowerShell fragments and depends on Strawberry Perl distribution.

PowerShell, rather conveniently, has an `-encodedCommand` flag that accepts a base64-encoded string and then processes it. This is helpful for avoiding quoting-related problems.

I tried the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work.

```
// powersheller.pl

#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;
use Encode qw/encode decode/;

use vars ('$powershell_command');

sub run_powershell_fragment {
    my ($contents) = @_;
    my $encoded = encode_base64($contents);
    printf "encoded: %s\n", $encoded;
    return `powershell.exe -noprofile -encodedCommand $encoded`;
}

printf "%s\n---\n", run_powershell_fragment($powershell_command);

BEGIN {
$powershell_command = <<EOF
echo "hi"   
EOF
}
```

And ran it. Here's the output of the ... standard output channels (?) from running the perl script in the powershell window.

```
PS C\...> perl .\powersheller.pl
encoded: ZWNobyAiaGkiCQo=

Redundant argument in printf at .\powersheller.pl line 18.
?????? : The term '??????' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

---
```

This looked like an encoding issue. I guessed that Perl was using something resembling utf-8 by default and powershell was expecting utf16-le or similar.

```
sub run_powershell_fragment {
    my ($contents) = @_;
    my $utf16_le_contents = encode("utf-16le", $contents);
    my $encoded = encode_base64($utf16_le_contents);
    printf "encoded: %s\n", $encoded;
    return `powershell.exe -noprofile -encodedCommand $encoded`;
}
```

Technically, using `"ucs-2le"` also works. I don't know which is appropriate.

Anyway, all together, the program works as expected with the extra conversion inserted.

```
PS C:\...> perl .\powersheller.pl
encoded: ZQBjAGgAbwAgACIAaABpACIACQAKAA==

hi

---
```

Why was this all that I needed to do? Is Perl handling conversions related to argv and stdout &c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

``` qx`` ``` performs no conversion. The command is expected to be encoded using the system's ANSI code page as it will be passed unmodified to `CreateProcessA` or similar.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
use Encode qw( encode );
use Win32  qw( );

my $cmd_ansi = encode("cp".Win32::GetACP(), $cmd);
`$cmd_ansi`
```

Of course, if the command contains only ASCII characters, encoding is moot.

---

Similarly, the values in `@ARGV` have not been decoded. They are received from the system encoded using the system's ANSI code page.

```
use Encode qw( decode );
use Win32  qw( );

my @decode_argv = map { decode("cp".Win32::GetACP(), $_) } @ARGV;
```

Of course, if the arguments contain only ASCII characters, decoding is moot.

---

By default, file handles do not perform any encoding or decoding except for CRLF ⇔ LF conversion (CRLF ⇒ LF on read, LF ⇒ CRLF on write). You are expected to provide a string of bytes (a string of characters with values in 0..255) to `print`/`printf`/`say`<sup>[1]</sup>, and you will receive a string of bytes from the `readline`/`read`/`readpipe`.

You may provide an encoding/decoding layer when opening the file.

```
open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $qfn)
```

You may provide an default encoding/decoding layer via the [open](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?open) pragma.

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
```

In both cases, you will now need to provide a string of Unicode Code Points to `print`/`printf`/`say`, and you will similarly receive a string of bytes from the `readline`/`read`/`readpipe`.

I'm not sure what's best for STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR, but you could start with the following:

```
use Win32 qw( );
my ($in_enc, $out_enc);
BEGIN {
   $in_enc  = "cp".Win32::GetConsoleCP();
   $out_enc = "cp".Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP();
   binmode STDIN,  ":encoding($in_enc)";
   binmode STDOUT, ":encoding($out_enc)";
   binmode STDERR, ":encoding($out_enc)";
}
```

---

You should use UTF-16le rather than UCS-2le.

---

1. If you provide a string that contains non-bytes (characters outside of 0..255), Perl will assumes you meant to encode the string using UTF-8. It will warn ("Wide character") and encode the string using utf8.